# Updating array values using higher order functions in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, closures

I’m struggling with using the new map, flatMap, filter, reduce and zip functions. Consider the following:
You have two arrays, A and B, containing different objects. For each object in A, you need to find the corresponding object in B (by their id property), and update some of the properties of the object from B. This could be done the old way, using two for cycles, like so:

```
private func update(statuses: [JobStatus], forJobs jobs: [JobBookPayload]) {
    for jobStatus in statuses {
        for job in jobs {
            if jobStatus.jobId == job.jobId {
                job.status = jobStatus.status!
                job.option = jobStatus.option!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done using the new functions, to make the code more "Swifty" and improve readability?

Comment: That *is* clear, readable code. – You'll always need a nested loop (explicit or hidden in a filter) unless you change the data structures.

Comment: It's not bad, I was just wondering if it could be achieved with the new functions in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that since you're using classes, you don't actually want to create a new object from the old one. I believe this could be achieved using `map` and `first` methods:

```
@discardableResult
func update(statuses: [JobStatus], forJobs jobs: [JobBookPayload]) -> [JobBookPayload] {
    return jobs.map({ (payload) -> JobBookPayload in
        if let status = statuses.first(where: { payload.jobId == $0.jobId }) {
            payload.status = status.status
            payload.option = status.option
        }
        return payload
    })
}
```

Using `@discardableResult` will allow you to use this function and ignore the resulting array - the objects inside the initial array were mutated anyway.

Comment: If you are discarding the result anyway, why make the function return anything? Could it not be done like so: _ = jobs.map({ ..., and have the function without a return value?

Comment: @damjandd can't argue with that, but is this approach actually better in any way?

Comment: Not really, I was just curious how it would be done using the new techniques and if it would make the code more readable. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

**Replacing `for .. in .. { if conditional { ... } }` with `for .. in .. where conditional { ... }`**

You could make a minor re-factoring by introducing a `where` clause in the inner `for` loop to replace the single `if` statement of its body:

```
private func update(statuses: [JobStatus], forJobs jobs: [JobBookPayload]) {
    for jobStatus in statuses {
        for job in jobs where jobStatus.jobId == job.jobId {
            job.status = jobStatus.status!
            job.option = jobStatus.option!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea in the "new" (functional) way, is to create a new object from the previous one:

```
private func update(statuses: [JobStatus], for jobs: [JobBookPayload]) -> [JobBookPayload] {
    return jobs.reduce([]) { newJobs, job in
        return newJobs + statuses.flatMap { status in
            return status.jobId == job.jobId ?
                //Construct a new object
                JobBookPayload(status: status.status, option: status.option) : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming there is one `status` object corresponding to a `job`:

```
private func update(statuses: [JobStatus], for jobs: [JobBookPayload]) -> [JobBookPayload] {
    return jobs.reduce([]) { newJobs, job in
        return newJobs + statuses.lazy.filter { $0.jobId == job.jobId }.first.flatMap { 
            JobBookPayload(status: $0.status, option: $0.option) // Construct the object
        }
    }
}
```

Avoiding `reduce`:

```
private func update(statuses: [JobStatus], for jobs: [JobBookPayload]) -> [JobBookPayload] {
    return jobs.flatMap { job in
        return statuses.flatMap { status in
            return status.jobId == job.jobId ?
                //Construct a new object
                JobBookPayload(status: status.status, option: status.option) : nil
        }.last
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks as if you are using `reduce` as a "map replacement", which is extremely inefficient because lots of intermediate arrays are created. Compare https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/

Comment: yeah, right, I could use `flatMap` here too, I prefer `reduce` for readability at times, plus afaik there's been another article recently where the exponential part of `reduce` has been removed, and it was taking linearly 1.5 times of a `map`

Comment: Do you have a link to that article? – Also this https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md should improve can help in Swift 4, when implemented.

Comment: Your second code does not compile. Created new `JobBookPayload` needs to keep `jobId` and other properties unchanged. You code returns a new Array where some elements are removed, which is completely wrong. The original code never deletes any elements from the Array of `JobBookPayload`.